# Unable to parse "WD-xsl" through java

Tags: xslt

I am using Transformer.transformer for applying xsl to the xml

When i use the following namespace it is not detected.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
```

Starting 
ERROR:  'The input document is not a stylesheet (the XSL namespace is not declared in the root element).' 
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

When i use the following namespace it is not detectedbut unable to compile completely as it is unable to detect few elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

ERROR:  'line 864: Unsupported XSL element 'eval'.' 
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet' 
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

The namespace `http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl` refers to a working draft that existed before XSLT 1.0 became a recommendation in 1999. Only old versions of Microsoft's MSXML support it on Windows, the last being MSXML 3.0. Don't expect to have support for that in the Java world. I don't think there is a direct way to use a stylesheet written for MSXML in the Java world, you would need to check which features outside of XSLT 1.0 it uses and check whether an XSLT 1.0 (like Saxon 6.5 or Xalan 2.7) processor supports it with the help of extensions or whether you can use an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor like Saxon 9.5 that supports a similar feature as a new part in XSLT 2.0 or [3.0](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!xsl-elements/evaluate) or at least as an [extension](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/evaluate).

Comment: Thank you for the inputs provided